# How to customize GridView vertical scrollbar?

Tags: android, gridview, scrollbar

I tried changing scrollbar of GridView:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
```

scrollbar_vertical_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#005A87"
        android:startColor="#007AB8" />

    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

scrollbar_vertical_track.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#9BA3C5"
        android:startColor="#8388A4" />

    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

But it's not working and gridview keeps showing original scrollbar.

Comment: accept his answer if it is working

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack=true
           android:scrollbars=vertical
```

if it didnt work then try  `android:scrollbarSize` too