# Gridview scroll width

Tags: android, gridview

I have this Gridview

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbarSize="30dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true">
</GridView>
```

for which I'm trying to increase the scroll width. I've tried using `scrollbarSize` but nothing changes. Is there a way to increase the width of the scrollbar without customizing it?

I'm new in Android development so please be gentle :)

Update: Tested this [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782499/how-can-i-change-the-width-thickness-of-a-scrollbar) and added my gridview inside the scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomMenu"
    android:scrollbarSize="50dip">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_holes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
    </GridView>
</ScrollView>
```

But the gridview is much more smaller and I'm seeing just the gridview thin scroll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the width/thickness of a scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782499/how-can-i-change-the-width-thickness-of-a-scrollbar)

Comment: Tested that answer and for me it's not working. That's why I posted this question. I've added the scrollview and inside my gridview but the gridview it's much more smaller :(

Comment: Try to customize your scrollbar ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471090/how-to-customize-gridview-vertical-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

please try this

> android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack=true
>
> android:scrollbars=vertical

Comment: Already tried this android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbarSize="30dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"     -Same result :(

Answer (score 0):

> use Scrollview for scrolling  sub view

**https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html**